# Script doesn't display in page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I tried this but it doesn't display inside the page. Where is the problem?

```
      $content ='
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="' . $this->app->getDef('text_products_favorites') . '" class="col-5 col-form-label">' . $this->app->getDef('text_products_favorites') . '</label>
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                        ' . HTML::checkboxField('products_favorites', 'yes', false) . '
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>      
      ';


      $output = <<<EOD
<script>
$('#tab9Content').prepend(
    '{$content}'
)
</script>
EOD;
        return $output;
```

If I change the script by this, it work fine and the information is displayed in the page

```
$('#tab9Content').prepend(
    '<h3>Brown</h3>' + 
    '<p>Brown Brown Brown</p>'
)
```

now in products.php

```
 <div class="adminformTitle" id="tab9Content">
</div>
```

If I edit mycode I have this.

```
<div class="adminformTitle" id="tab9Content">
<script>
$('#tab9Content').prepend(
    '
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="text_products_favorites" class="col-5 col-form-label">text_products_favorites</label>
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="products_favorite" id="products_favorite" value="yes" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>      
      '
)
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: In your edited code you need to use `+` concatenation between the strings for every next line like `'<h3>Brown</h3>' + 
    '<p>'`, then it should work

Comment: ok, but I have just {$content} to display and it is only '{content}'  and not after. don't follow sorry

Comment: you mean your `php $content` you want to `prepend`?

Comment: See the answer below, it work fine.

Comment: finally you are using `concatenation` for each line break, that is what i told you in first comment,

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with this change :

```
 $content = '<div class="row">';
 $content .= '<div class="col-md-9">';
 $content .= '<div class="form-group row">';
 $content .= '<label for="' . $this->app->getDef('text_products_favorites') . '" class="col-5 col-form-label">' . $this->app->getDef('text_products_favorites') . '</label>';
 $content .= '<div class="col-md-5">';
 $content .= HTML::checkboxField('products_favorites', 'yes', false);
 $content .= '</div>';
 $content .= '</div>';
 $content .= '</div>';
 $content .= '</div>';
```